# Filtering distance matrix with R

Tags: r

I converted a distance matrix to a two column `data.frame`, I want to filter out the "diagonals" and ">0" values, keeping identical objects.

I have a distance matrix like

```
mat<-c(0,0.5,0,0.5,0,0.3,0,0.3,0)
dim(mat)<-c(3,3)
rownames(mat)<-c("A","B","C")
colnames(mat)<-c("A","B","C")
```

I tried

```
df = as.data.table(mat)
df1 <- stack(df)
setDT(df1)
df1[, pp := colnames(df)]
setkey(df1, values)
```

Which gives

```
    values ind pp
1:    0.0   A  A
2:    0.0   A  C
3:    0.0   B  B
4:    0.0   C  A
5:    0.0   C  C
6:    0.3   B  C
7:    0.3   C  B
8:    0.5   A  B
9:    0.5   B  A
```

What I need:

```
    values ind pp
1:    0.0   A  C
```

Comment: Shouldn't `values` be `1.0` for (`A`, `C`)?

Comment: you are absolutely right, my mistake, it is a distance matrix

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; not my downvote btw. Downvotes are not warranted here. Question constains sample data, clear problem statement, reproducible code and expected output.

Comment: is this still an issue or did the type fix it?

Comment: Still an issue.

Comment: I am not sure how you get your expected output when there are no 0's in `mat`. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @FaustinoDelgado I really struggle to understand your expected output. How do you end up with a `0` for element (`A`, `C`)? You say that `mat` is a distance matrix, but `mat` has a value of `1.0` for element (`A`, `C`). Provided this is not a typo, we need more details. I can't reproduce the "Which gives" output either (there are no `0` entries when I try to reproduce `df1`). If there are in fact typos, you need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54412351/edit) your post; don't add fundamental changes in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, it was an edition mistake, when I was building the matrix I first tested an identity matrix and then a distance matrix without changing the code for the input on the script, sorry, the 1's in the input are the 0s in the output.

Comment: I think the code is clean now. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it :

```
mat <- c(1,0.5,0,0.5,1,0.3,0,0.3,1)
dim(mat) <- c(3,3)
rownames(mat) <- c("A","B","C")
colnames(mat) <- c("A","B","C")

cond <- mat == 0 & upper.tri(mat, FALSE)
pos <- which(cond, arr.ind = TRUE)
data.frame(values = mat[pos], ind = rownames(mat)[pos[,1]], pp = rownames(mat)[pos[,2]])
```

cond is a boolean matrix of your condition, values equals to 0, not diagnonal and upper triangular matrix to remove duplicated index of the symetric matrix.